# how can i redirect in axios interceptor?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i wrote an `axios interceptor` for refresh token in vue js (main.js) and i want when i get `401` error status code in my project it try for getting new token with my refresh_token and send request again with new token
if the refresh token is not valid too i want to redirect to login page and break the axios requests
but my problem is when refresh token is not valid i will stuck in loop of refresh token api call and i will get multiple error `(duplicate navigation)` in console
another problem is i cant catch error in `catch block` and always it goes to `then block` and response is `undefined`

```
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        return response
    },
    function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL + process.env.VUE_APP_REFRESH_TOKEN,
                {
                    "refresh_token": localStorage.getItem("refresh_token")
                })
                .then(res => {
                        localStorage.setItem("token", "Bearer " + res.data.result.access_token);
                        originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem("token");
                        return axios(originalRequest);
                }).catch(error=>{
                    console.log(error);
                    router.push({'name':'login'})
            })
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a flag. For example,

```
let isAlready401=false
axios.interceptors.response.use((response) => {
        return response
    },
    function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;
        if (!isAlready401&&error.response.status === 401) {
            isAlready401 = true
            axios.post(process.env.VUE_APP_BASE_URL + process.env.VUE_APP_REFRESH_TOKEN,
                {
                    "refresh_token": localStorage.getItem("refresh_token")
                })
                .then(res => {
                        localStorage.setItem("token", "Bearer " + res.data.result.access_token);
                        originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = localStorage.getItem("token");
                        return axios(originalRequest);
                }).catch(error=>{
                    console.log(error);
                    router.push({'name':'login'})
                    isAlready401 = false
            })
        }
    });
```

Comment: works tnx but would you help why i get 401 header status code in refresh token api it doesnt go to catch block and then login . it always go to then block now . reason that it goes to catch block now and my code works is i dont have data in response

Comment: Does `axios(originalRequest)` should go to `catch` block? @sinak

Comment: @sinak You can add `then` and `catch` after `axios(originalRequest)` to see the result.

Comment: i want to get result of `refresh token api call` and i wrote the then and catch after that but it goes always to then even when hedaer is 401 and response is undefined . i am confused

Comment: Ok, so you need to import the router where the interceptor is defined?